# What does an average monster in the Starter Set look like?

Tags: dnd-5e, monsters, published-adventures, lost-mine-of-phandelver

Based on the monsters that have been previewed so far by WOTC (we've seen 4 from the starter so far, 3 are easily found [here](http://www.wizards.com/DnD/Article.aspx?x=dnd/4ex/20140626)). We've only really seen a small range of Challenge levels (all 3 in the starter page previewed are Challenge 2).

Based on the contents of the Starter Set, what does an average monster of each CR level look like (1/2, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5).

It would be helpful to know things like:

- Monster HP
- Monster AC
- At Will To Hit
- Avg Damage done on a hit.

Collecting this information will be very helpful for determining baselines for combat effectiveness in PCs. Obviously we won't know what design goals underline these until we get the DMG, but learning what the average monster of a specific Challenge level looks like will be very helpful to me (and others) as I construct characters.

Comment: Two eyes, two arms, two legs, strange-colored skin, sharp teeth and claws.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Here are the stats you asked for with some caveats...**

For reference to those who don't know what challenge rating is set to in 5e, CR means that a party of 4 "well-rested" adventures should be able to defeat a monster with equal CR to their party level without suffering casualties.

| CR | AC | HP | To-hit | Avg damage | # of spellcasters |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 10 | 4 | 2 | 2 | 0 |
| 1/8 | 13 | 5 | 3.66 | 4 | 0 |
| 1/4 | 12.25 | 13.25 | 3.75 | 5.25 | 0 |
| 1/2 | 15 | 14 | 4 | 6.33 | 0 |
| 1 | 14 | 24.8 | 4.2 | 7.2 | 1 |
| 2 | 12.4 | 40.6 | 4.6 | 8.4 | 1 |
| 3 | 13.5 | 48.75 | 4.75 | 9.75 | 1 |
| 4 | 13 | 40 | 5 | 10 | 1 |
| 8 | 18 | 136 | 7 | 15 | 0 |

- As you can see, there is no level 5 CR monster in the starter kit but there is a level 8.
- I've included the number of spell casters in each level because they generally tend to have low defenses and HP (bringing down the overall CR average) and higher damage spell slot spells not calculated that would up their actual damage output (all basis damage was using their most damaging at-will/cantrip magical attacks).
- One of the spellcasters is actually a magical creature, but its ability to make multiple magic attacks (that weren't spells) on each turn vs it's terrible melee attack made it seem to fit the category.
- The spellcaster in CR 2 has mage armor, I took the value of his AC with Mage armor active.